# Limit CGVector's length while keeping its direction

Tags: ios, macos, vector, core-graphics

I need to move between two SpriteKit nodes with a `CGVector`, whose length is, for example, 100 (red arrow).

But I want to limit the vector's length to 70, if it's more than 70 (green arrow). So, I need to "cut" the red vector's length, but keep its direction.

[image: Drawing of a vector showing actual length and limited length]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have a variable `v` of type `CGVector`. First, you compute its length:

```
double len = hypot(v.dx, v.dy);
```

Then, if it's greater than 70, you divide both components by `len` and multiply by 70 to make the vector's length equal to 70:

```
if (len > 70.0)
{
    v.dx *= 70.0 / len;
    v.dy *= 70.0 / len;
}
```